# Common Lisp Equivalent of `man`

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm using clozure common lisp. Is there a common lisp equivalent of the unix `man` command or something analgous?

Comment: The best source for standard functions is the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/). If you're using Emacs+SLIME, you can use "C-c C-d h" to look up functions in it. Personally I like to have Emacs configured to use an offline copy (for instant page load) of the hyperspec in Eww (works well in text-mode too).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see docstrings and other symbol information in Common Lisp REPL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093513/how-to-see-docstrings-and-other-symbol-information-in-common-lisp-repl)

Answer (score 5):

Start with [`describe`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_descri.htm).

You might also want to consider [`documentation`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_docume.htm), but that is lower level.

Comment: Don't forget the very useful (and sharing the same name as the similar command line tool) [**apropos**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apropo.htm)

Answer (score 4):

As [jkiiski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747548/jkiiski) commented you, Hyperspec is the best online documentation of standard functions for Common Lisp. You can download it for offline use [here](ftp://ftp.lispworks.com/pub/software_tools/reference/HyperSpec-7-0.tar.gz).

If you also want to document your own code, you can use either:

```
(defun simple-function (a b)
  "Documentation of a simple function"
  (+ a b))
```

or this:

```
(defun simple-function (a b)
  (:documentation "Documentation of a simple function")
  (+ a b))
```

as [sds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850781/sds) suggested, you can access the docstring by:

```
(describe #'simple-function)
```

or in an interactive way with:

```
(inspect #'simple-function)
```

A good SO answer about Common Lisp documentation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5093808/5690687).

Comment: Minor nit: the documentation [_has_ to be a string](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm), not a list prefixed by the `:documentation` keyword.